# EndTransactionLLSRQ INVLD ITIN

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to cancel some flights/segments but I'm getting this response. I couldn't find any resources related to this error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-09-14T03:10:49",
    "request": {
        "confirmationId": "AGNTGJ",
        "retrieveBooking": false,
        "errorHandlingPolicy": "HALT_ON_ERROR",
        "cancelAll": false,
        "flights": [
            {
                "itemId": "24"
            },
            {
                "itemId": "43"
            }
        ]
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "category": "CANCELLATION_ERROR",
            "type": "UNABLE_TO_CANCEL",
            "description": "Operation of ending transaction failed"
        },
        {
            "category": "WARNING",
            "type": "END_TRANSACTION_PROBLEM",
            "description": "#APPLICATION: [com.sabre.services.stl_payload.v02_01.SystemSpecificResults@53c22e6e[messages={com.sabre.services.stl_messagecommon.v02_01.MessageCondition@1cd5a587[value=Unable to recover from EndTransactionLLSRQ error. Please see below messages for details, code=ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR]}]]"
        },
        {
            "category": "WARNING",
            "type": "END_TRANSACTION_PROBLEM",
            "description": "#BUSINESS_LOGIC: [com.sabre.services.stl_payload.v02_01.SystemSpecificResults@bb8e049[messages={com.sabre.services.stl_messagecommon.v02_01.MessageCondition@7561fff0[value=EndTransactionLLSRQ: INVLD ITIN, code=WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE]}]]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the request:

```
{
    "confirmationId": "AGNTGJ",
    "errorHandlingPolicy": "HALT_ON_ERROR",
    "flights": [
        {
            "itemId": "24"
        },
        {
            "itemId": "43"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried sending the request. Am expecting the cancellation to succeed but returns errors.

Comment: _"I'm trying to cancel some flights/segments"_ - not my trip to Cancun tomorrow, I hope!

Comment: @Dai no worries. we re-scheduled your trip instead

Comment: can you tell me more details about how can you cancel PNR